# Extract POST DATA using beanshell assertion

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, beanshell, assertion

Given my original question below, I've envisioned a way to do it. It seems that the data that I need is in the POST data in my "Request". Anyone have an idea on how am I going to be able to extract "SampleText.txt" from this:

```
sample
    --MbxZ3_yI7Q32k5mz-ThR6RMeCwF-DXdXjJbxIB2
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadVideoFile"; filename="SampleText.txt"
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

I am testing this website: http://www.the-v.net/en/vtube/upload-video.
Its main function is to perform video uploads, notice that it only allows `MOV, MP4, M4V, AVI, 3GP, 3GP2, ASF, WMV, MPEG formats`.

I've created a test plan which uploads files with different formats (3GP, MP4, PPT, XLS, among others).
Would it be possible to use beanshell assertion to write on the log the type of file that has been uploaded? I am new to beanshell scripting, all I know right now is how to check the response data and write on the response message if a test case passed or not.

Is it possible to write on the log file or as a response message the type of file being sent or the parameters sent?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy function for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) in JMeter.

So in order to print parameters to the *jmeter.log* file you can use [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the following Groovy code:

```
def mySampleFile = sampler.getHTTPFiles()[0]

log.info('File name: ' + mySampleFile.getPath())
log.info('File type: ' + mySampleFile.getMimeType())
log.info('File parameter name: ' + mySampleFile.getParamName())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Assertion Print Parameters]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)